# Getting the InnerXML of an Element using REXML Document and Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, rexml

I have looked everywhere I think, but not found an answer.

I am consuming a SOAP API and I wish to store only part of the response in the database as XML.

The code is as follows:

```
require 'rexml/document'
doc = REXML::Document.new(response.to_xml)
data = doc.root.elements['//SearchResult'].to_s
```

This gives me all the XML inside the  node of my response.

I want only the **contents** of that node, not the node.

Right now I get:

```
<SearchResult>
    <bla></bla>
    <bla2></bla2>
</SearchResult>
```

But I only want:

```
<bla></bla>
<bla2></bla2>
```

I'm using ruby 1.9.3-head with Rails 3.2.x.

I found a .value() method somewhere but that doesn't work on elements, which is what I get from the XPath search.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
doc.root.elements['//SearchResult'].elements.each do | elem |
  p elem
end
```

gives

```
<bla> ... </>
<bla2> ... </>
```

So, with

```
data = doc.root.elements['//SearchResult'].elements.map(&:to_s)
```

you can retrieve an array of `String` representations of all sub-nodes.

Comment: Nice one. I had thought of this but I kept looking for conventional 'innerXML' or 'value' methods from the source lib. For the sake of expedience, I'm going to presume this is the only way :)